# Задачка "как соотносятся служба в конкретном виде войск и получаемая в процессе этой службы профессия"

Tags: sql, oracle

**Имеется** следующая структура БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код таблиц:

```
-- Таблица войск
CREATE TABLE troops(
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR2(100)
);

-- Таблица профессий
CREATE TABLE profession(
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR2(100)
);

-- Таблица возможных вариантов отслужить в конкретной воинской части
CREATE TABLE military_unit_duty(
  military_unit_id INT,           -- Номер воинской части
  troops_id INT,                  -- Войска
  profession_id INT               -- Профессия
);
```

Заполнение таблиц:

```
-- Добавление войск и профессий в воинские части
-- Есть 4 воинские части: 3660, 3656, 40911, 74330

----- Мотострелки-водители
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3660, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3656, 3, 1);
----- Мотострелки-повара
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3660, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3656, 3, 2);
----- Мотострелки-механники
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3660, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3656, 3, 3);
----- Мотострелки-связисты
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3660, 3, 7);

----- Моряки-повара
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (40911, 2, 2);
----- Моряки-механики 
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (40911, 2, 3);
----- Моряки-штурманы
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (40911, 2, 5);
----- Моряки-картографы
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (40911, 2, 6);
----- Моряки-связисты
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (40911, 2, 7);

----- Ракетные-повара
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (74330, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3656, 4, 2);
----- Ракетные-картограф
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (74330, 4, 6);
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3656, 4, 6);
----- Ракетные-связист
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (74330, 4, 7);
INSERT INTO military_unit_duty VALUES (3656, 4, 7);
```

**Задание:** *Как соотносятся служба в конкретном виде войск и получаемая в процессе этой службы профессия? Результат запроса выдать в форме, например:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В базах данных я только начинаю разбираться и не понимаю с чего даже начать писать запрос, чтобы достичь поставленной задачи. Пожалуйста, подскажите в какую сторону двигаться.

Comment: Что у вас получилось до сих пор? Запрос можно начать писать так: `select ... from ... where ...`.

Comment: А вы в таком виде данные из БД не получите, если не перечислите в запросе все профессии. Потому что БД может вернуть строго определенное в тексте запроса количество столбцов. добавлять столбцы динамически она не будет. Так что, либо выводите строками, "войска, профессия, да/нет". Если сильно хочется колонки, то вам поможет `pivot` (но в нем придется перечислить нужные профессии)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить задачку следующим образом:

```
SELECT "Войска", lISTAGG("Профессия", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
"Профессия") AS "Профессии" FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT t.name AS "Войска", p.name AS "Профессия" FROM 
military_unit_duty mud INNER JOIN troops t ON mud.troops_id=t.id
INNER JOIN profession p ON mud.profession_id=p.id
) GROUP BY "Войска";
```

Результат:

[image: Результат работы программы]